# In Java,Can I make executable Jar file with a command line program?

Tags: java, command-line, deployment, export

In java,I am making a program that has no GUI. Can I made executable jar file with it? And distribute it?. I'd there any other ways to distribute command line programs?

Comment: Sure you can. What exactly are you trying to figure out?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: Friends, it says that I have to configye my launch...what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can [make a executable jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html), no matter with or without GUI.

All we need to do is add the `Main-Class` in the `MANIFEST.MF` of the jar file to indicate the main class name in the jar package:

```
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```